# Options for ingesting and processing data in Azure sql

Tags: azure-sql-database, etl, data-processing

I need expert opinion on a project I am working on. We currently get data files that we load into our Azure sql database using a local script that calls stored procedures. I am planning on replacing the script with ssis jobs to load the data into our Azure Sql but wondering if that's a good option given our needs.I am opened to different suggestions too. The process we go through is to load data file to staging tables and validate before making updates to live tables. The validation and updates are done by calling stored procedures...so the ssis package will just load the data and make calls to those stored procedures. I have looked at ADF IR and Databricks but they seem overkill but am open to hear people with experience using those as well. I am currently running the ssis package locally as well. Any suggestion on better architecture or tools for this scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just BULK INSERT data from Azure Blob Store:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15#accessing-data-in-a-csv-file-referencing-an-azure-blob-storage-location

Then you can use ADF (no IR) or Databricks or Azure Batch or Azure Elastic Jobs to schedule the execution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll set up tests for the options you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely have a look at  Azure Data Factory Data flows. With this you can easily build your ETL pipelines in the a Azure Data Factory GUI.

In the following example two text files from a Blob Storage are read, joined, a surrogate key is added and finally the data is loaded to Azure Synapse Analytics (would be the same for Azure SQL):

[image: ADF Data flows]

You finally put this Mapping Data Flow into a pipeline and can trigger it, e. g. if new data arrives.